# How to use flash solution with jPlayer (Firefox)

Tags: flash, firefox, jplayer

I'm trying to install `jPlayer` on my website but it's not working on Firefox (22.0). The playlist is only displayed if I click on the random button, and then I can to play a song but the progress bar is always empty.
When the DOM is ready, the list is empty (div with jp-playlist class).

Here is the code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var jplayer = new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"                                       
            }, [{
                    title="My title",
                    mp3 : "/music/my_song.mp3"
               },
               {
                   title="My title2",
                   mp3 : "/music/my_song2.mp3"
               }], 
            {
                    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
                    supplied: "mp3",
                    volume: .7,
                    wmode:"window",
                    solution: "html,flash"
            });
    });
</script>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-270p">
    <div class="jp-type-playlist">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div class="jp-gui">
            <div class="jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                <div class="jp-controls-holder">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">Jouer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">Pause</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">Stop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">Suivant</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="sound-bar">
                        <ul class="jp-controls sound">
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="Muet">Mute</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="Actif">Unmute</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="Volume max">Volume max</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                            <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="jp-toggles">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="Al&eacute;atoire">Al&eacute;atoire</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="D&eacute;sactiver al&eacute;atoire">Non al&eacute;atoire</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="R&eacute;p&eacute;ter">R&eacute;p&eacute;ter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="D&eacute;sactiver r&eacute;p&eacute;tition">Ne pas r&eacute;p&eacute;ter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-title">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-playlist">
            <ul>
                <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered list -->
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jPlayer/jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jPlayer/add-on/playlist.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",`  to « `swfPath: "js",`.

I believe the `swfPath` should be the path to the folder that holds the `.swf` file, not a normal path the the file itself.

"The Jplayer.swf file must be uploaded to your server. The default location is relative to your current page in a folder named "js". To modify the location of the Flash file, use the swfPath constructor option. Below is how to set the `swfPath` to a path relative to the server root. See the jPlayer({swfPath}) constructor option for more information." - http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the player for audiojs. It's perfect :)